# Unable to login to ALM using python

Tags: python, alm

I am trying to login to ALM and fetch all defects by python code.
But I am not able to login

```
import win32com.client
import win32api
import pythoncom
def get_QCConnection():
    '''Get the hardcoded connection to the server and domain.
    Can be made a "real" engine if you try hard.
    Use makepy utility to determine if the version number has changed (TDApiOle80)
    but this works to current version'''

    QCConnection =win32com.client.Dispatch("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")
    url = 'http://alm12ypdmz:8080/qcbin'
    QCConnection.InitConnectionEx(url)
    QCConnection.login('msb','Welcome*01')
    QCConnection.Connect('DEFAULT','NEWGEN_SYS_TEST')    
    return QCConnection
conn = get_QCConnection()
```

com_error: (-2147221164, 'Class not registered', None, None)

Comment: Use REST API instead. It will be very easy

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/macroking/ALM-Integration 

List of REST API Endpoints: https://github.com/macroking/ALM-Integration/blob/master/end-points.json

Answer (score 1):

this `com_error` is because `TDConnect.exe` is not installed,

visit http://alm12ypdmz:8080/qcbin/(your alm url) tools and download, HP ALM Connectivity tool,

`TDConncect.exe` and install it.